# Least-strict (*)

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible to implement `(*)` with least-strict semantics in Haskell (standardized Haskell preferred, but extensions are OK.  Using compiler internals is cheating)?  For example, such a definition should result in the following being true:

```
0 * ⊥ = 0
⊥ * 0 = 0
```

and only:

```
⊥ * ⊥ = ⊥
```

I can build pattern matches that satisfy one of the above cases, but not both, because the zero check forces the value.

Comment: Do you mean in practice (via unsafe things like spoon) or in theory is this somehow unsafe or in practice by only using H2010?

Comment: You could probably do this for a limited number of cases, such as where the bottom value results from a call to `error`. However, being able to recognize any bottom value would amount to solving the halting problem. What should happen if the first argument is a non-terminating computation?

Comment: @sabauma if one absolutely must check for equality with 0, then that's probably true, and would be an explanation for why this might not be possible.

Comment: @singpolyma Even if you are not comparing with zero, the first pattern must ensure that the second argument is indeed bottom before it can return zero.  This is more due to the fact that you are pattern matching on bottom.

Comment: @sabauma obviously one cannot pattern match on bottom :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, but only using constrained impurity.

```
laziestMult :: Num a => a -> a -> a
laziestMult a b = (a * b) `unamb` (b * a)
```

here [`unamb`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb) is Conal Elliott's "pure" variant of `amb`.  Operationally, `amb` runs two computations in parallel, returning which ever comes first.  Denotationally `unamb` takes two values where one is strictly greater (in the domain theory sense) than the other, and returns the greater one.  **Edit: also this is unamb, not lub, so you need to have them equal unless one is bottom.**  Thus, you have a semantic requirement that must hold even though it can't be enforced by the type system.  This is implemented as essentially:

```
unamb a b = unsafePerformIO $ amb a b
```

much work goes into making this all work correctly with exceptions/resource management/thread safety.

`laziestMult` is correct if `*` is commutative.  It is "least strict" if `*` is non strict in one argument.

For more, see [Conal's](http://conal.net/blog/posts/functional-concurrency-with-unambiguous-choice) blog

Comment: Your definition of `unamb` is nearly correct, but you forgot an important precondition: if neither argument is ⊥, then they must be exactly equal.

Comment: The package also has function [`parCommute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html#v:parCommute) just for this case, so you could write just `parComb (*)`.

Answer (score 12):

Phillip JF's answer only applies to flat domains, but there are `Num` instances which are not flat, for example the lazy naturals.  When you go into this arena, things get quite subtle.

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
    deriving (Show)

instance Num Nat where
    x + Zero = x
    x + Succ y = Succ (x + y)

    x * Zero = Zero
    x * Succ y = x + x * y

    fromInteger 0 = Zero
    fromInteger n = Succ (fromInteger (n-1))

    -- we won't need the other definitions
```

It is especially important for lazy naturals that operations be least-strict, since that is the domain of their usage; e.g. we use them to compare lengths of possibly infinite lists, and if its operations are not least-strict, then that will diverge when there is useful information to be found.

As expected, `(+)` is not commutative:

```
ghci> undefined + Succ undefined
Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> Succ undefined + undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So we will apply the standard trick to make it so:

```
laxPlus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
laxPlus a b = (a + b) `unamb` (b + a)
```

which seems to work, at first

```
 ghci> undefined `laxPlus` Succ undefined
 Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
 ghci> Succ undefined `laxPlus` undefined
 Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

but in fact it does not

```
 ghci> Succ (Succ undefined) `laxPlus` Succ undefined
 Succ (Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
 ghci> Succ undefined `laxPlus` Succ (Succ undefined)
 Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

This is because `Nat` is not a flat domain, and `unamb` only applies to flat domains.  It is for this reason that I consider `unamb` a low-level primitive that should not be used except to define higher level concepts -- it should be irrelevant whether a domain is flat. Using `unamb` will be sensitive to refactors that change the domain structure -- the same reason `seq` is semantically ugly.  We need to generalize `unamb` the same way `seq` is generalized to `deeqSeq`: this is done in the [`Data.Lub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lub/0.1.7/doc/html/Data-Lub.html) module.  We first need to write a `HasLub` instance for `Nat`:

```
instance HasLub Nat where
    lub a b = unambs [
                  case a of
                      Zero -> Zero
                      Succ _ -> Succ (pa `lub` pb),
                  case b of
                      Zero -> Zero
                      Succ _ -> Succ (pa `lub` pb)
              ]
        where
        Succ pa = a
        Succ pb = b
```

Assuming this is correct, which is not necessarily the case (it's my third try so far), we can now write `laxPlus'`:

```
laxPlus' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
laxPlus' a b = (a + b) `lub` (b + a)
```

and it actually works:

```
ghci> Succ undefined `laxPlus'` Succ (Succ undefined)
Succ (Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
ghci> Succ (Succ undefined) `laxPlus'` Succ undefined
Succ (Succ *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

So we are driven to generalize that the least-strict pattern for commutative binary operators is:

```
leastStrict :: (HasLub a) => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
leastStrict f x y = f x y `lub` f y x
```

At the very least, it is guaranteed to be commutative.  But, alas, there are further problems:

```
ghci> Succ (Succ undefined) `laxPlus'` Succ (Succ undefined)
Succ (Succ *** Exception: BothBottom
```

We expect the sum of two numbers which are at least 2 to be at least 4, but here we get a number which is only at least 2.  I cannot come up with a way to modify `leastStrict` to give us the result we want, at least not without introducing a new class constraint.  To fix this problem, we need to dig into the recursive definition, and simultaneously pattern match on both arguments at every step:

```
laxPlus'' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
laxPlus'' a b = lubs [
    case a of
        Zero -> b
        Succ a' -> Succ (a' `laxPlus''` b),
    case b of
        Zero -> a
        Succ b' -> Succ (a `laxPlus''` b')
    ]
```

And *finally* we get one that gives as much information as possible, I believe:

```
ghci> Succ (Succ undefined) `laxPlus''` Succ (Succ undefined)
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ *** Exception: BothBottom
```

If we apply the same pattern to times, we get something that seems to work as well:

```
laxMult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
laxMult a b = lubs [
    case a of
        Zero -> Zero
        Succ a' -> b `laxPlus''` (a' `laxMult` b),
    case b of
        Zero -> Zero
        Succ b' -> a `laxPlus''` (a `laxMult` b')
    ]

ghci> Succ (Succ undefined) `laxMult` Succ (Succ (Succ undefined))
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ *** Exception: BothBottom
```

Needless to say, there is some repeated code here, and developing the patterns to express these functions as succinctly (and thus with as few opportunities for error) as possible would be an interesting exercise.  However, we have another problem...

```
asLeast :: Nat -> Nat
atLeast Zero = undefined
atLeast (Succ n) = Succ (atLeast n)

ghci> atLeast 7 `laxMult` atLeast 7
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ ^CInterrupted.
```

It is dreadfully slow.  Clearly this is because it is (at least) exponential in the size of its arguments, descending into two branches on each recursion.  It will require yet more subtlety to get it to run in reasonable time.

Least-strict programming is relatively unexplored territory, and there is necessity for more research, both in implementation and practical applications.  I am excited by it and consider it promising territory.

Comment: I think `Nat` should only refer to inductive naturals: either the flat domain `Nat = Z | S!Nat` or the true discrete set.  `Nat` should not contain values like `x = S x` since no natural number has that form.  Instead, we should call the "lazy naturals" something else, perhaps the "supernatural numbers"?

Comment: @PhilipJF, do you also object to calling `[]` "list"?

Comment: a litte bit.  Not as much as `Nat` though, since "list" is such a "cs" word, while naturals are a very well defined and important notion in mathematics.